# Why am I failing to get my JQuery tooltip to work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found this really cool [Toolbar.js](https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/) JQuery library that I would love to add to my application, though the instructions on the page seem pretty straightforward, I am having issues getting it to work.

Find below my simple HTML file put together as per instructions:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.toolbar.js"></script>
          <link href="css/jquery.toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
          
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#gear').toolbar({
                    content: '#toolbar-options',
                    position: 'top'
                });
            }); 
          </script>
          
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <header>
            <h1>Testing toolbar.js</h1>
        </header>

            <div class="btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
            </div>
            
            <div id="toolbar-options" class="hidden btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-primary">
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a>
            </div>          

    </body>
</html>
```

The browser console does not render any error messages.
The HTML code renders the following image, but doesn't render the tooltips as desired:

[image: The rendered page that HTML code renders]

Help!
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, haven't looked at the library, but could be because you are assigning multiple `ids` which is invalid. (`id="toolbar-options gear"`)

Comment: Try wrapping your code inside  `$(document).ready(function() {..`

Comment: @VictorIvanov Mmm... Which one do you think I should remove?

Comment: @Swati Thanks, I tried this but it didnt help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prevent multiple elements with the same ID

   ```
   id="gear"
   ```
2. Prevent elements with multiple ID's

   ```
   id="toolbar-options gear"
   ```
3. Add toolbar css CDN link (instead off local file)

   ```
   <link hef="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/paulkinzett/toolbar@1.0.1/jquery.toolbars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
   ```

---

- After fixing those issues, it still doesn't seem to work.
- It's appears the `position: 'bottom'` causes the error.
- Setting it to top works as you can see in this demo:

  ```js
  $('#gear').toolbar({
      content: '#toolbar-options',
      position: 'top'
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .hidden { display: none; }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/paulkinzett/toolbar@1.0.1/jquery.toolbar.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/paulkinzett/toolbar@1.0.1/jquery.toolbars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <header>
      <h1>Testing toolbar.js</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-warning" id="gear" >
      <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
  </div>

  <div id="toolbar-options" class="hidden btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-primary">
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a>
  </div>
  ```

---

The error is thrown in `getCoordinates` which shows:

```js
getCoordinates: function( position, adjustment) {
    var self = this; 
    self.coordinates = self.$elem.offset();
    if(position == 'top') { 
        return coordinates = {
            left: self.coordinates.left-(self.toolbar.width()/2)+(self.$elem.width()/2),
            top: self.coordinates.top-self.$elem.height()-adjustment,
        }
    }

    if(position == 'left') { 
        return coordinates = {
            left: self.coordinates.left-(self.toolbar.width()/2)-(self.$elem.width()/2)-adjustment,
            top: self.coordinates.top-(self.toolbar.height()/2)+(self.$elem.height()/2),
        }
    }

},
```

Since the function does not return anything if the value is `bottom`, it makes sense that an error is thrown.

Comment: Am not sure how you are able to get it to work on your end, but am still not able to get it to work on my end.

Comment: Does the snippet work for you? Maybe update your question with your latest code?

Comment: No the snippet didnt work at all. I have updated the question with the latest code as per request.

Comment: WHy didn't the snippet in my answer work? ANy errors? Kinda weird since its working fine here. You need to press the icon.

Comment: Sorry am not sure what exactly happened but it just started working. I must have forgotten to update it or something. Thanks a bunch you've saved me hours of frustration!